# using maps for visual studios 2012 for windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am trying for the first time to get an app going on my windows phone. For my first real project I though I would display a map on my phone with my center being my own gps coordinates. Unfortunately I have run into every problem imaginable and google for the first time has been 0 help to me. Right now whenever I open the app on my phone it shows me a blank screen. here is my code for the xaml.

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="GPSTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <m:Map x:Name="MainMap"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Height="748"
           Margin="10,10,10,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           ZoomLevel="14" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage
```

and this my code in the code behind: xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GPSTest.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Threading;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;


namespace GPSTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {



        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            OneShotLocation();
        }
        private async void OneShotLocation()
        {

            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

            try
            {
                Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                    maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                    );

               Double DLat = Convert.ToDouble(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00"));
               Double DLong = Convert.ToDouble(geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00"));
               MainMap.Center.Latitude = DLat;
               MainMap.Center.Longitude = DLong;
            }
```

I have heard i need to add a reference to bing maps,Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic, but cant add it as it does not show up in my reference list. And something about getting a key. I went and got one but cant put it in the CredentialsProvider= because it says its not needed.

Their seems to be alot of outdated code out their and that might be the problem. Thank you in advance I am truly bewildered on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in Windows phone 8, here Nokia maps can be implemented so no key required for that

so now for your currnet location use this code

```
Geolocator geoLocator = new Geolocator();

            Geoposition geoPosition = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = geoPosition.Coordinate;

            GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeoCoOrdinate(myGeocoordinate);

            // mapWithMyLocation.Center = myGeoCoordinate;
            mapWithMyLocation.SetView(myGeoCoordinate , 10, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);
```

because of this new maps there is a difference in Geocoordinate and GeoCoordinate. so you have to convert this so for that use this converter method

```
 public static GeoCoordinate ConvertGeoCoOrdinate(Geocoordinate geoCooridinate)
        {
            return new GeoCoordinate(
                geoCooridinate.Latitude,
                geoCooridinate.Longitude,
                geoCooridinate.Altitude ?? double.NaN,
                geoCooridinate.Accuracy,
                geoCooridinate.AltitudeAccuracy ?? double.NaN,
                geoCooridinate.Speed ?? double.NaN,
                geoCooridinate.Heading ?? double.NaN);
        }
```

it is quite easy isn't it? :-)